# Why is NFSv4 not translating POSIX ACL's in a usable way?

Tags: linux, acl, xfs, nfsv4

I have an XFS filesystem in which some folders (using mode setting) have no public accessiblity, with group owner having read-only privileges.  There is a program (which runs as user cryosparc_user) which needs read access to all the files, so I added a default POSIX ACL granting cryosparc_user read access.

Unfortunately most of the processing is done on workstations which NFSv4 mount this filesystem, and for some reason the POSIX ACLs aren't being translated or honored on the workstation (well, they are, but not in a usable way apparently), and I can't figure out why.

Both server and workstation are running Ubuntu 18.04, and I can't simply add cryosparc_user to the group, as the group is an Active Directory security group (we're doing authentication through AD), and cryosparc_user is a local user which can't be set up in AD.

Here are the permissions on the fileserver:

```
root@kraken:/EM/EMtifs# getfacl pgoetz
# file: pgoetz
# owner: pgoetz
# group: cns-cnsitlabusers
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:cryosparc_user:r-x
default:group::r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---

root@kraken:/EM/EMtifs# id cryosparc_user
uid=1017(cryosparc_user) gid=1017(cryosparc_user) groups=1017(cryosparc_user),10002(mclellan),10003(taylorlab)
```

Here is what they look like on the workstation with the NFSv4 mount:

```
root@javelina:/EM/EMtifs# getfacl pgoetz
# file: pgoetz
# owner: pgoetz
# group: cns-cnsitlabusers
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---

root@javelina:/EM/EMtifs# id cryosparc_user
uid=1017(cryosparc_user) gid=1017(cryosparc_user) groups=1017(cryosparc_user)

root@javelina:/EM/EMtifs# nfs4_getfacl pgoetz
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A::GROUP@:rxtcy
A::EVERYONE@:tcy
A:fdi:OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A:fdi:1017:rxtcy
A:fdi:GROUP@:rxtcy
A:fdi:EVERYONE@:tcy
```

Notice the 3rd line from the bottom in the NFS4 ACL query.  The cryosparc_user user seems to be afforded read acces (local UID is 1017 on both systems), however

```
cryosparc_user@javelina:/EM/EMtifs$ whoami
cryosparc_user
cryosparc_user@javelina:/EM/EMtifs$ ls pgoetz
ls: cannot open directory 'pgoetz': Permission denied
```

From everything I've read there are no mount flags to set or anything like this; this should just work automatically and I can't figure out why it's not working.

My fallback plan is to revert to using local groups on these folders (so that cryosparc_user can be added to the local group), but this would require duplicating AD authentication structure on each system, which will be a maintenance headache.

Another idea was to also do a read-only SMB mount of this filesystem using cryosparc_user user credentials for the mount, but I'm not terribly excited about double mounting a 500T filesystem, either.  I'd rather authentication just work in a rational way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem turned out to be a failure to understand how POSIX ACLs work; in particular I assumed that **default** ACLs set permissions on the directory they've been applied to, when in fact these only apply to subdirectories and files *created after the default ACL's have been applied to the parent object* and don't in fact apply the parent object at all.

What tipped me off was an appeal the NFS developers list regarding this issue.  One of the developers pointed out (**and this is important to know**) that NFS is entirely agnostic about this and simply appeals to the permissions set on the server's underlying filesystem.  That pointed me in the direction of looking at the POSIX ACLs on the server filesystem and -- after some experimentation (this is poorly documented) -- I realized the functionality described above and recreated the POSIX ACLs to actually do what I wanted them to do.  The issue went away after that.

Answer (score 2):

Something that might be called POSIX ACLs does not exist.

There was a standard proposal draft from aprox. 1993 that was withdrawn in 1997 because users did not like this kind of ACL implementation.

The only standard for ACLs that exists is NFSv4.

Try to use a modern operating system that supports NFSv4 ACLs.

Comment: Just curious: what modern operating system supports NFSv4 ACL's natively, which I take to mean at the level of the underlying server filesystem?  It would be great if linux began supporting these, but all efforts to make ti happen have been thwarted.

Comment: BTW, the POSIX ACL draft was withdrawn largely because of Windows NTFS ACLs.  It became clear that POSIX ACLs didn't provide enough granularity to be compatible with NTFS (and that some of the NTFS stuff was useful).  AFAIK all modern linux filesystems (e.g. ext4 and XFS) provide POSIX ACL functionality by default.

Comment: NFSv4 ACLs are supported natively by AIX, Mac OS X, Solaris, FreeBSD and probably more. Solaris and FreeBSD do this via ZFS.